# .NET MailKit read messages from two mailboxes in one account

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit to read email from Ms Exchange account.
Everything works fine, but what if corm\john.doe had two mailboxes "john.doe1@corp.com" and "john.doe2@corp.com".

There is no parameter for mailbox address in Mailkit flow

```cs
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
        client.Connect ("imap.corp.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

        client.Authenticate ("corp\\john doe", "password");

        client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

        var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.All);

        foreach (var uid in uids) {
            var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (uid);

            // write the message to a file
            message.WriteTo (string.Format ("{0}.eml", uid));
        }

        client.Disconnect (true);
    }
```

How to read messages from both mailboxes?

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling a "mailbox" is what other people would call an "account", so what you would do is use 2 ImapClients and use them to login to each of the 2 accounts:

```
using var client1 = new ImapClient();
using var client2 = new ImapClient();

client1.Connect ("imap.corp.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
client2.Connect ("imap.corp.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

client1.Authenticate ("corp\\john doe1", "password");
client2.Authenticate ("corp\\john doe2", "password");
```

Comment: I am not an expert in Ms Exchange. But my account seems to have two mailboxes. At least I see both in Ms Outlook. That is, there is one account (corp\john.doe), and two mailboxes (john.doe1@corp.com and john.doe2@corp.com)